# Empty css file in loading index.php

Tags: php, html, css

In a way of divide php code from HTML. I got a problem in loading css file.
So I have php file index.php, css file - main.css,and html files front.html and  log_in.html

```
<?php

    $door = file_get_contents("log_in.html");
    $Page = file_get_contents("Front.html");
        $Page = str_replace("{{Door_frame}}", $door, $Page); 
    echo $Page;  // if you know better variant to get page from php please let me know.

?>
```

Here I try to put the login container in front.html page. I thing it is better to do that create another similar page.

if I go to directory localhost/my-site/  (it automatically take index.php or index.html if i understand correct)
it show me the website perfectly. Everything work.
But as soon as I get localhost/my-site/index.php it get me page  with empty css file  (see the attached pictures).
So the question: why does it happening? Is it not the same address localhost/my-site/ and localhost/my-site/index.php?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Press `F12` and see if you have a console error.

Comment: sorry forget to upload pictures. Please look. There is no mistake because it is still work correctly in a first variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you enter localhost/site-final/index.php (without / on the end)? I think it's trying to load localhost/site-final/index.php/css/main.css when you have index.php/. You could use absolute path to your css file (http://localhost/site-final/css/main.css).

Comment: yes you right i didn't pay atention to the path. Thanks. I kill more than 2hour trying to find what is happen. thanks.